# ¿Se debería mantener consistencia en las etiquetas con otros sitios de SE?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Voy a empezar con un ejemplo y algo de contexto: En computación hay varias cosas que se pueden llamar bootstrap. Esto [generó problemas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250920/bootstrap-tags-revisited) [en el sitio en inglés](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309933/we-gave-bootstrap-the-boot-but-it-wasnt-heavy-enough) porque se estaba usando la etiqueta [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) para todos los casos cuando se había definido inicialmente para uno (procesos que se ejecutan al inicio), aunque casi todas las preguntas eran de otro (el *framework* de diseño web). Por eso se acabó "*burninando*" la etiqueta [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) y redefiniendo nuevas etiquetas para cada caso en particular: [twitter-bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap), [bootstrapping](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping), [bootstrapper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapper), [bootstrap-protocol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-protocol), [statistics-bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statistics-bootstrap)...

En StackOverflow en español están apareciendo preguntas sobre Bootstrap (el *framework* de diseño web) y se están etiquetando con [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap). Lo cual está bien porque aquí no se tiene el problema del sitio en inglés donde la etiqueta ya estaba definida.

Comprendo que los son sitios independientes, pero **¿se debería mantener consistencia entre los sitios de SE e intentar que las etiquetas con nombres de productos/tecnologías se mantengan igual de uno a otro?**

No me refiero a mantener los nombres en inglés de las etiquetas de tecnologías o disciplinas (ej: [base-de-datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-de-datos), [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos) o [reescritura-url](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reescritura-url) están perfecto), sino a ser consistentes en cuanto a las etiquetas con "nombres propios" de lenguajes, aplicaciones y/o productos, como por ejemplo:

- Bootstrap (utilizar [twitter-bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) en lugar de [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap)),
- Google Maps (usar [google-maps](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps) en lugar de [mapas-de-google](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapas-de-google)),
- Google Sheets ([google-sheets](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) en lugar de [google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo)),
- Etc.

Comment: Me parece que es reto gigante lograr la consistencia de las etiquetas debido a que estas son mantenidas por la comunidad en particular si se usan etiquetas muy específicas ya que algunos privilegios sobre las etiquetas están reservados a usuarios que tengan una alta reputación en la etiqueta correspondiente (véase [Privilegios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges))

Comment: En relación a los ejemplos de Google, el propio Google usa nombres distintos para sus productos en la documentación, material de marketing y otras publicaciones de los mismos. Incluso en ocasiones varía si el usuario usa su cuenta en español de España o en español de Latinoamérica y ciertos casos poco frecuentes pero que han existido, hay variantes por idioma-país.

Comment: Que algunos productos cambien de nombre de un país a otro (incluso usando el mismo idioma) es mayor motivo para estandarizar las etiquetas en una sola y crear sinónimos que apunten a esa única etiqueta. Mi sugerencia sería que esa única etiqueta (si fuera posible) tuviera el mismo nombre en las diferentes versiones de SO, porque haría más fácil la adaptación de un sitio a otro.

Comment: Sobre el tamaño del reto, sería gigante si se tuvieran que adaptar dos sitios como SO (que tiene +46.000 etiquetas diferentes, y +3.000 sinónimos). Pero SOes apenas tiene 435 etiquetas (y 2 sinónimos). De esas, sólo una parte es sobre nombres propios y muchos de ellos no cambian de idioma a idioma por lo que la etiqueta es la misma en SO y SOes y no requerirían cambio ni sinónimo.

Comment: El tamaño del reto no sólo es por el número de etiquetas sino también por la coordinación que implica de los usuarios, actuales y futuros, con cuenta en otros sitios de SE y sin ella, asiduos y ocasionales, hablantes de una o varias lenguas, etc. Me parece que lo conveniente es proceder etiqueta por etiqueta, así se reduce mucho la complejidad.

Comment: @Rubén, el aspecto wiki del site permite que nosotros mismos cuidemos de hacer ese mantenimiento y que tomemos decisiones más o menos democráticas al respecto. Me parece muy sensible intentar definir cuáles serán las guías taxonómicas aquí del SOes ahora mismo mientras empieza. Por tus comentarios, parece que ya tienes material para redactar una respuesta exponiendo tu posición. Intentaré hacer lo mismo.

Comment: @brasofilo: Sobre la primera parte de tu comentario, exacto, el aspecto wiki del site lo permite, pero ciertas tareas requieren de privilegios y para ello de reputación. Por otro lado para crear etiquetas se requiere de preguntas, el deber ser es que las etiquetas se creen de forma orgánica. Creo que antes sofisticar el sitio debemos enfocarnos en lo básico: 1. Preguntar, Responder y Votar. 2. Terminar la traducción de artículos de ayuda. 3. Promover el sitio.

Comment: @Rubén el enlace a folcsonomía apunta a privilegios, ¿podrías compartirlo de nuevo?¿o es el enlace a la wikipedia? Es por curiosidad para ver si es otra fuente mejor

Comment: En el caso particular de Bootstrap debería quedarse como [tag:bootstrap]. *Bootstrap* como proceso de carga al inicio es una palabra en inglés no un nombre propio así que no habría confusión. Además que el nombre correcto del framework web es **Bootstrap**, hace tiempo dejó de llamarse Twitter Bootstrap,

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: El enlace sobre Folcsonomía debía apuntar a https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folcsonomía. Lamentablemente no se pueden editar los comentarios, así que lo borré, considerando que está en mi respuesta.

Comment: El el caso de Google pondría, `mapas-google` en vez de `mapas-de-google`, ya que la palabra _de_, es una preposición, y lo mismo en la otra, `google-hoja-calculo`, o `google-hoja-cálculo` con tilde.

Answer (score 3):

No, no creo que se deben de usar etiquetas consistentes con el resto de SE.

Mi opinion se basa en que somos una comunidad semi-autónoma cuyas necesidades son diferentes a las de otros sitios.  Para poder beneficiar de las etiquetas ya establecidas, podríamos continuar usando los sinónimos.  Pienso que las etiquetas deberían nacer orgánicamente y evolucionar conforme cresca la comunidad.

Hay casos en que se pueden planear las diferentes etiquetas - como en el case de [bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) - pero eso *no implica que debemos usar cada variante*.

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

> ¿Se debería mantener consistencia en las etiquetas con otros sitios de
>   SE?

Como aspiración, sí para las etiquetas icónicas, pero no para todas. Sin embargo, creo que debemos enfocarnos en los indicadores de la beta pública.

## En breve

Me parece que no deberíamos imponernos el hacer de forma exhaustiva (todas las etiquetas, todo el tiempo, en todos los sitios) ya que en SE las etiquetas son definidas por los usuarios de cada sitio y esto implica no sólo hacerlo del lado de SOes sino también en los otros sitios además de considerar otros factores. A lo cual me refería en la edición inicial de esta respuesta como "lineamientos folsonómicos".

Un tema como los lineamientos "folcsonónmicos", es decir, poner reglas para asegurar la consistencia de todas las etiquetas de todas las temáticas que abarcará SOes con los sitios correspondientes en otros idiomas me parece muy sofisticado para el momento actual:

- menos de noventa días
- pocos usuarios con privilegios suficientes para tareas relacionadas con los wikis de las etiquetas
  ...

Me parece que durante la beta pública debemos enfocarnos en:

1. Incrementar el número de preguntas, respuestas y votos.
2. Terminar la traducción de artículos de ayuda.
3. Incrementar el número de usuarios ávidos.

Y que lo relacionado con las etiquetas surja orgánicamente.

## Explicación

¿Realmente es necesario explicar lo anterior y ampliar? Yo creo que sí, van algunas ideas

1. Cómo funcionan las etiquetas y los scripts relacionados con las mismas
2. Auto borrado de preguntas que tendrían como consecuenta la eliminación de etiquetas.

## Relacionado

- https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges
- [¿Cuáles son las etiquetas icónicas relativas a nombres de productos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408/cu%C3%A1les-son-las-etiquetas-relativas-a-nombres-de-productos)
- [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

Comment: Rubén creo que no estas contestando la pregunta, yo creo que es el momento ideal para tratar estos temas antes que se tenga que hacer esfuerzos masivos para retagear cientos de preguntas.

Comment: @Carlos,  por tu comentario veo que si habría que explicar y ampliar :).