# ¿Cuáles son las etiquetas icónicas relativas a nombres de productos?

Tags: discusión

En relación a [¿Se debería mantener consistencia en las etiquetas con otros sitios de SE?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393/se-deber%c3%ada-mantener-consistencia-en-las-etiquetas-con-otros-sitios-de-se)

> ¿se debería mantener consistencia entre los sitios de SE e intentar
>   que las etiquetas con nombres de productos/tecnologías se mantengan
>   igual de uno a otro?

Por cada etiqueta que debería ser manejada de forma consistente entre los sitios de SE agregar una respuesta indicando

1. URL de la página canónica sobre el producto/tecnología

   1. URL a la página en español
   2. URL a la página en inglés
2. Nombre oficial
3. Sitios de SE que utilizan etiquetas a homologar

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets / Hojas de Cálculo

### URLs páginas canónicas

- En español: https://www.google.com/sheets/about/?hl=es
- En inglés: https://www.google.com/sheets/about/?hl=en

### Nombre oficial

- En español: Hojas de Cálculo
- En inglés: Sheets

### Sitios de SE que utilizan etiquetas a homologar

- http://stackoverflow.com .

  - Etiquetas: [google-spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)
- http://webapps.stackexchange.com

  - Etiquetas: [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets)

### Etiquetas relacionadas en SOes

- [google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo)