# ¿Cómo crear o solicitar una nueva etiqueta?

Tags: soporte, faq, etiquetas

Me gustaría solicitar una etiqueta [julia-lang](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia-lang) homóloga a la de su contraparte en inglés:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia-lang

Esto para ayudar al esparcimiento de el conocimiento sobre el lenguaje de programación Julia:

- http://julialang.org
- http://julialanges.github.io (versión en español - en progreso)

Actualmente casi todas las preguntas y respuestas se realizan a través de nuestro chat:

- https://gitter.im/JuliaLangEs/julialang-es

Pero de esta manera se pierden entre el mar de comentarios, cuando bien podrían ser útiles para una audiencia mas amplia.

Aunque también hay varios grupos y recursos bajo JuliaLangEs:

- https://github.com/JuliaLangEs
- https://www.facebook.com/groups/julialang.es
- http://www.meetup.com/julialanges-mx
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julialanges
- https://twitter.com/JuliaLangsEs
- https://www.linkedin.com/grp/home?gid=8335583

Ninguno es tan bueno como el formato que StackOverflow en Español ofrece, creo que esto facilitaría el crecimiento de la comunidad de Julia de usuarios de habla hispana.

Ya hay algunos proyectos en proceso para internacionalizar Julia y su documentación:

- https://gitter.im/JuliaLangEs/julia-i18n
- https://www.transifex.com/julialang-i18n/julialang-web
- https://crowdin.com/project/julia-doc/activity_stream

Creo que este es el siguiente paso y yo alentare a los miembros de la comunidad a usar Stack Overflow en español con dicha etiqueta.

En Stack Overflow en inglés tengo 1357 puntos y soy muy activo en el tag `julia-lang`, estoy a 143 puntos de poder crear etiquetas, pero lamentablemente eso no me sirve de nada aquí ya que hay que empezar de cero.

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/2374329/ismael-venegas-castell%C3%B3?tab=topactivity

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: Como dice la pregunta que enlace @Gepser puedes hacer una pregunta y cuando alguno la editemos crear la etiqueta adecuada :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## En breve

Publica preguntas aún y cuando todavía no exista la etiqueta

## Explicación

Para crear una nueva etiqueta, debe de haber una pregunta. Tu mismo puedes publicar preguntas. Si aún no cuentas con la reputación suficiente deberás esperar a que otro usuario con la reputación suficiente agregue la etiqueta o bien esperar a tener la reputación suficiente para agregar tu mismo la etiqueta.

Puedes empezar por publicar algunas preguntas frecuentes e incluso traducir preguntas realizadas en [Stack Oveflow](http://stackoverflow.com). En estos casos lo apropiado es que se publique simultáneamente la respuesta.

Se requieren [**300 puntos de reputación**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) para poder crear etiquetas.

Para que una etiqueta persista más de 6 meses, debe de haber al menos una segunda pregunta con ella.

**Referencias**

Ayuda de Stack Overflow en español

- [Creación De Etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
- [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debo usarlas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)
- [¿Puedo apoyar mi producto en este sitio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Meta de Stack Overflow en español

- [¿Se debería mantener consistencia en las etiquetas con otros sitios de SE?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393/se-deber%C3%ADa-mantener-consistencia-en-las-etiquetas-con-otros-sitios-de-se)
- [¿Cuáles son las etiquetas icónicas relativas a nombres de productos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408/cu%C3%A1les-son-las-etiquetas-ic%C3%B3nicas-relativas-a-nombres-de-productos)
- [¿Son aceptables las traducciones directas de respuestas de StackOverflow en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-directas-de-respuestas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl)