# Quemar en la hoguera la etiqueta [dispositivos]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Hoy les vengo a hablar (espero que sea la única vez) acerca de la etiqueta [dispositivos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dispositivos):

- Como ***demasiadas*** etiquetas en SO Español, esta solo se usa en [una única pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108540/diferencias-en-jquery-en-localhost-y-servidor).
- La etiqueta se llama dispositivos... ¿Pero qué clase de dispositivos? La etiqueta en sí es muy amplia, y abarca *demasiados* tipos de dispositivos, pues pueden ser desde una Micro SD hasta una PC o Servidor.

¿Qué dicen?

Comment: El proceso de quemado es necesario cuando es una etiqueta recurrente y con bastante uso. En este caso hay apenas un uso, lo que quiere decir que, si no se añade a ninguna otra pregunta, en 6 meses el sistema la eliminará directamente (referencia: [¿Cómo crear o solicitar una nueva etiqueta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/441/83)). O puedes acelerarlo tú directamente quitándosela :)

Comment: ... Y si se edita, haciendo que la etiqueta quede huérfana, se elimina automáticamente a las 03:00 UTC ([How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/304899))

Comment: He editado la pregunta para quitar la etiqueta [tag:dispositivos] y añadir [tag:javascript] en su lugar. Ya que no tiene pregunta asociada, será eliminada en unas horas.

Answer (score 4):

Después de quitar la etiqueta de la única pregunta que la tenía (y esperar a que corriera el proceso que borra etiquetas huérfanas a las 3:00 UTC), la etiqueta [dispositivos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dispositivos) ha sido borrada.

Como se indica en los comentarios, no parece que haga falta quemarla porque no es una etiqueta muy usada. Si más adelante su uso se extiende, podemos volver a revisar esta decisión.