# Crear etiqueta [rxjs]

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas

Creo que sería interesante craer la etiqueta [rxjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rxjs) para preguntas relacionadas con la librería RxJS orientada a la programción reactiva.

Esta librería se usa por ejemplo en Angular (está fuertemente integrada con Angular).

Stack Overflow la tiene: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rxjs

Comment: El privilegio de crear etiquetas nuevas se consigue a los 1500 de reputación. Pero hay que tener en cuenta que una nueva etiqueta se eliminará si no es utilizada suficientemente automaticamente (al menos otra pregunta con esa etiqueta en los siguiente 6 meses)

Comment: He visto varias para ponerle la etiqueta. Cómo no tengo priviliegios, lo pido aquí.

Comment: Vale...visto que hay varias preguntas efectivamente parece que la etiqueta puede ser útil así que la he creado. Ahora sería bueno que la editeis [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rxjs) para poner la orientacion de uso y la informacion.

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo crear o solicitar una nueva etiqueta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/440/c%c3%b3mo-crear-o-solicitar-una-nueva-etiqueta)

Comment: @fedorqui en la pregunta que enlazas se habla de 300 puntos para crear etiquetas. Es posible que eso fuera antes de la graduación del sitio?

Comment: @Pikoh buena pregunta. Se ve que son 150 en Beta y 300 para graduados. Veo que Mariano lo editó para actualizar la info una vez se graduó el sitio (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/441/revisions)

Comment: @fedorqui olvidalo, 1500 son necesarios en el sitio en ingles, en este 300. Pensé que eran los mismo...

Comment: @Pikoh ostras tienes razón, nunca me había dado cuenta de la gran diferencia entre sitios. En Meta.SE es 500 por ejemplo https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges y 300 en el resto (fuente https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95497/209901)

Comment: @fedorqui a mi tambien me ha sorprendido mucho. Pensé que tras la graduación estos privilegios sería iguales, nunca me ha dado por compararlo hasta hoy...

Comment: @Pikoh Me sonaba que habíamos traducido [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/209901) pero no la encuentro. Sería una buena fuente para ver estas cosas.

Comment: @fedorqui claro, si no lo pego no puede funcionar :) Era [este](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1813/15301)

Comment: @Pikoh ah genial! Me sigue sonando que alguien puso la tabla en markdown. Lo mismo fue Luiggi y lo eliminó. No sé, bueno tanto da

Comment: En cualquier caso no es duplicada porque no pregunto cómo crear una etiqueta, sino que pido que que alguien con privilegios la cree ya que yo no puedo crearla. Igualmente ya esa creada así que se puede dar por solucionada (pero cómo no hay respuestas no puedo marcar como resuelta).

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, esta pregunta no es duplicada de ¿Cómo crear o solicitar una nueva etiqueta?

Comment: Por cierto [meta-tag:característica-nueva] debería usarse sólo para solicitar cambios que requieran la intervención de un desarrollador de "la compañía". Cuando se trate de una solicitud para usuarios con privilegios incluyendo a los moderadores ♦ considero que se debe usar [meta-tag:soporte]

Comment: @Rubén, creo que debería indicarsae más claramente en las etiquetas obligatoprias que hay que poner. Cómo no sabía cuál usar busqué otra pregunta que pidiese crear una etiqueta y ví qué etiqueta tenía, que era "característica-nueva", por eso usé esa.

Comment: @sanzante se habla sobre las etiquetas requeridas aquí: [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) :)

Comment: Ya, pero de ahí no se deduce cuál es la etiqueta a usar cuando se quiere crear una nueva etiqueta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

La etiqueta ya fue creada.

Comment: esto no es una respuesta :P si eso, que un moderador añada la etiqueta

Comment: La etiqueta ya está creada. Voy a dar la respuesta por buena para que la pregunta no quede como sin responder.